# The getter items was called on null

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-futurebuilder

I am working on a simple ListView app that gets populated from the internet and storing in the database using Provider. But the ListView doesn't get populated. It was getting null on items getter. But after I changed with Consumer.

Now I got an error, The getter items was called on null.

stackoverflow

```
 ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (15505): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<void>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (15505): _FutureBuilderState<void>#7948f):
I/flutter (15505): The getter 'items' was called on null.
I/flutter (15505): Receiver: null
I/flutter (15505): Tried calling: items
I/flutter (15505): 
I/flutter (15505): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (15505):   FutureBuilder<void>
I/flutter (15505):   file:///C:/Users/Admin/lib/main.dart:27:13
I/flutter (15505): 
I/flutter (15505): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (15505): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
I/flutter (15505): #1      _MyAppState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:list_cart_interview/main.dart:37:33)
I/flutter (15505): #2      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:751:55)
I/flutter (15505): #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4744:28)
I/flutter (15505): #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4627:15)
I/flutter (15505): #5      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'models/product.dart';
import 'provider/product_provider.dart';
import 'widgets/list_item.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: ProductsProvider(),
        child: MyApp(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
              .getProducts(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }

            print(snapshot.data.items.length);
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return Consumer<ProductsProvider>(
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
                builder: (context, productProvider, child) =>
                    productProvider.items.length <= 0
                        ? child
                        : ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: productProvider.items.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListItem();
                            },
                          ),
              );
            }
            return Container();
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

**product_provider.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:list_cart_interview/hellper/sqlite_helper.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import '../models/product.dart';

class ProductsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Products> _items = [];

  List get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  Future<void> getDataFromInternet() async {
    try {
      Response response = await get('https://jsonkeeper.com/b/YIDG');

      Map<String, dynamic> extractedData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      final length = extractedData['data']['products'].length;
      print(length);

      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        DatabaseHelper.insert({
          'id': extractedData['data']['products'][i]['prodCode'],
          'prodName': extractedData['data']['products'][i]['prodName'],
          'prodImage': extractedData['data']['products'][i]['prodImage'],
          'prodPrice': extractedData['data']['products'][i]['prodPrice'],
          'cartQuantity': 0,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }

  Future getProducts() async {
    await getDataFromInternet();
    final productsList = await DatabaseHelper.getProductsFromDB();
    print(" hbj ${productsList}");

    _items = productsList
        .map(
          (item) => Products(
            item['id'],
            item['prodName'],
            item['prodImage'],
            item['prodPrice'],
            item['cartQuantity'],
          ),
        )
        .toList();
    print('-items: ${_items}');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I think getProducts() method is making the problem in above code.
Now getting an only child is this widget. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether your `snapshot.data` has data or not before accessing the items.

```
if(snapshot.hasData) {
  // return your ListView
}
```

Comment: I checked already, it getting null, no actual values. that's the problem

Comment: when I tried to map out the items, it won't pass to _items.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using Providers with FutureBuilder.
FutureBuilders depend on a Future i.e. a value is eventually returned.
In your case the provider calls `notifyListeners();` and ends at that.
There is nothing being returned.
If you wish to use the items list, use a consumer which listens for changes.

If using a FutureBuilder is absolutely necessary, have your `getProducts()` method return some value which the `FutureBuilder` can use.
For example, you could return a boolean value based on whether you are getting data or not.